# Bluetooth won't turn on since upgrading to 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

Since I updated to 16.04, I'm having problems starting Bluetooth.
In recent weeks sometimes restarting my laptop fixed it, but now it won't turn on under any circumstances.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I added it to startup

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local

rfkill unblock bluetooth
```

And now it's working. Hope it keeps that way

Answer (score -1):

On 20.04 I was able to resolve this by reloading the `btusb` module as described in [this blog post](https://techstoriesindia.blogspot.com/2020/05/fix-ubuntu-20-04-bluetooth-doesnt-turn-on.html):

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter below commands one after another.

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```